# Find the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x) = \left|\cos^2(x) - \frac{3}{4}\right|$ on $[0,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find the absolute maximum and minimum of $f(x) = \left|\cos^2(x) - \frac{3}{4}\right|$ on $[0,\pi]$

I have learnt that in order to find the absolute maximum, I need to check the value of the function at the:

1. sides of $[0,\pi ]$
2. in points that the function isn't differentiable.
3. in points that satisfy $f'(x)=0$

How do I approach this question? I have no idea how to differentiate it with the absolute value, and how could I find the points that aren't differentiable in $[0,\pi ]$. 
 any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\cos^2 x \le \frac{3}{4} \iff -\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\le \cos x\le \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$.

Comment: What is the range of $\cos^2 x$ on $[0,\pi]$?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I missed up on that, now I can write my function as 2 parts:  $x\le \frac {\pi } {6} $ and $ \frac {\pi } {6} <x \le \pi $, right?

Comment: $\cos^2x $ is a number between $0$ and $1$ inclusive, so $\cos^2x-\frac 34$ is a number between $-\frac 34$ and $\frac 14$. Taking the absolute value changes the range to $[0,\frac 34]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I will give you some (big) hints:

1. Notice that when $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{6}\right]$ we have $\left|\cos^2\left(x\right)-\frac{3}{4}\right|=\cos^2\left(x\right)-\frac{3}{4}$;
2. Notice that when $x\in\left[\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}\right]$ we have $\left|\cos^2\left(x\right)-\frac{3}{4}\right|=\frac{3}{4}-\cos^2\left(x\right)$;
3. Notice that when $x\in\left[\frac{5\pi}{6},\pi\right]$ we have $\left|\cos^2\left(x\right)-\frac{3}{4}\right|=\cos^2\left(x\right)-\frac{3}{4}$;
4. Notice that:

$$\cos^2\left(x\right)=\frac{1+\cos\left(2x\right)}{2}\tag1$$

5. Notice that:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos^2\left(x\right)-\frac{3}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(1\right)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos\left(2x\right)\right)\right\}-\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(1\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left\{0+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\cos\left(2x\right)\right)\right\}-\frac{3}{4}\cdot0=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin\left(2x\right)\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(2x\right)=$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin\left(2x\right)\cdot2\cdot\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sin\left(2x\right)\cdot2\cdot1=-\sin\left(2x\right)\tag2$$

5. Notice that, likewise $(2)$ only with a flipped sign:

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\frac{3}{4}-\cos^2\left(x\right)\right)=\sin\left(2x\right)\tag3$$

Comment: Thanks! This really clears it, but I got one question about the 3rd line where you said when $x\in [0, \frac {5\pi } {6} ]$ , is it a typo and you meant $x\in [\frac {5\pi } {6} , \pi ]$?

Comment: @Pwaol you're right, I fixed it. I am glad that I could help you.